# How should I fill out a "what I'm looking for" section of an online profile if what I'm looking for does not define my current job?

Tags: startup, networking, tech-industry

On a popular job profile website in my sector, there's a section for what you're looking for in a company. While I'm not *explicitly* looking right now, if I was, I'd be looking for something quite different than my current environment. For example, I might write something like:

> A high Joel test score - private offices with doors that close, a well-defined and not "unlimited" vacation policy, and no alcohol or ping pong tables being provided in lieu of monetary compensation. Basically, "serious engineering with serious engineers".

However, since this is attached to my name and *all* of these are the exact opposite of my current job, that might be a bit blatant if someone from the company I work at saw it.

How should I fill out this section, if at all?

Answer (score 3):

Are you putting up a professional profile for an engineering position, or are you trying to get a job as a comedian?

It's best to make a professional profile, especially if you want to do serious work, with serious engineers. Poking fun at your current situation is firstly only going to be understood by your current coworkers, and secondly comes across as a bit childish at best. So if you're trying to be lighthearted it's going to go straight over the heads of anyone who doesn't know your current situation and therefore won't work.

Comment: How would you edit this, then? Nothing was intended as a joke. For example, Fog Creek exemplifies the environment that I am interested in - perhaps obvious as I mention the Joel Test and "private offices with doors that close", two phrases heavily linked to that company.

Comment: The implication is that this is not the work environment you're in, it's poking fun at your current placement. That's how I see it anyway.as a third party. Basically you're NOT doing serious engineering with serious engineers.

Comment: I would go with the usual guff, 'I'm looking for an innovative company with a chance of advancement and professional workforce'. Stuff like that. Then the implication is that you're a keen, ambitious professional looking for a career. Not a disgruntled employee looking for a way out.

Comment: Ah, I'm not disgruntled, I actually like my job a lot. These items are what it would take to *get me away* from there, so I'm only interested in being contacted by companies that fulfill them (and also have the good things about the company I work at).

Comment: Makes no difference whether you are or not, you have a few sentences to make an impression don't put anything that could even vaguely be construed as negative, someone will only skim through this, don't get dumped on the first look. It's not what you mean, but what the readers perception is that matters... just my opinion.

Comment: @charl Kilisi is right here: that text reflects badly on you. If I read that I would at best consider it someone trying too hard to be witty or to stand out (for the wrong reasons). At worst I'd consider it immature and unprofessional. I certainly wouldn't think "what a serious engineer".

Comment: I disagree with the above answer and comments. Your text tells me that you are self aware and know what you want which in my book puts you well above the crowd. "The usual guff" as proposed in the third comment bores me to death and tell me that you are an average joe.

Comment: For most roles, I'm looking for the solid average Joe, with the correct skills and work ethic etc,. not a prima donna or idiot savant.